# split by comma inside a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this

```
var str = "n,m,'klj,klp',ml,io"; // not the quotes arround klj,klp
```

I use javascripts `.split()` but it returns like this

```
n
m
klj
klp
ml
io
```

But I  need it as below,not getting any idea

```
n
m
klj,klp
ml
io
```

Comment: Couldn't possible without a hack..! :p

Comment: if (string.indexOf(',') > -1) is fine?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a split function does it? I assume you mean the standard JavaScript string `.split()` function.

Comment: There are tons of CSV parsers out there that weigh very little and are very fast - use one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly, simple:

```
"n,m,'klj,klp',ml,io,'test,test,a,b','test',test".
    match( /'[^']+'|[^,]+/g ).
    map( function( x ) { return x.replace( /^'|'$/g, '' ) } );
```

Result:

```
["n", "m", "klj,klp", "ml", "io", "test,test,a,b", "test", "test"]
```

If this sample is from a CSV file, you have to look out for more gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
var splitStrings = (function () {
  var regex = /'.*?'/g;

  return function (str) {
    var results = [], matches;
    matches = str.match(regex);
    if (matches) {
      results = matches.map(function (match) {
        return match.substring(1, match.length-1);
      });
    }
    return results.concat(str.replace(regex, '').split(',').filter(function (s) {
      return s !== '';
    }));
  };
})();
```

It is a function wrapped inside a closure to keep the regex private.

```
console.log(splitStrings("n,m,'klj,klp',ml,io"));
// prints ["klj,klp", "n", "m", "ml", "io"]
```

The example from [Zsolt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27076913/2193410):

```
console.log(splitStrings("n,m,'klj,klp',ml,io,'test,test,a,b','test',test"));
// prints ["klj,klp", "test,test,a,b", "test", "n", "m", "ml", "io", "test"]
```

Note that the function doesn't preserve the order of strings.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to not hardcode values AS I have done,there is another way then only above match....map function work

add this incase you are refering from selectbox,textbox etc...

```
var newValue = $(".client option:selected").text();

      if (/,/i.test(newValue)) {
         newValue = "'" + newValue + "'";
     }
newValue.match( /'[^']+'|[^,]+/g ).
    map( function( x ) { return x.replace( /^'|'$/g, '' ) } );
```

Answer (score 0):

C-like solution

```
function em_split(str) {
    var ret = [], p0 = 0, p1 = 0, p2 = 0, pe = 0;
    while ((p1 = str.indexOf(",",pe)) != -1) {
        if ((p2 = str.indexOf("'",pe)) != -1 ) {
            if (p2 < p1) {
                if (p2==pe) {
                    pe = ((p2 = str.indexOf("'",p1)) == -1) ? p1 : p2;
                } else pe = p1;
            } else pe = p1;
        } else { pe = p1; }
        ret.push(str.substr(p0,pe-p0));
        pe = (pe == p2) ? pe+2 : pe+1;
        p0 = pe;
    }
    ret.push(str.substr(p0,str.length));
    return ret;
}
```

example use:

```
console.log(em_split("n,m,'klj,klp',ml,io"));
console.log(em_split("n,m,'klj,klp,ml,io"));
console.log(em_split("n,m,klj,klp',ml,io"));
```

will return:

```
Array [ "n", "m", "'klj,klp", "ml", "io" ]
Array [ "n", "m", "'klj", "klp", "ml", "io" ]
Array [ "n", "m", "klj", "klp'", "ml", "io" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.split()` method with `regex` for this.

```js
var str = "n,m,'klj,klp',nl,'klj,x,y,klp','klj,klp',ml,io";
var splits = str.split(/'([^']+)'|([^,]+)/);
var results = splits.filter(function(v){
    if (v && v!== ",")
        return true;
    return false;
});

document.write("<br>Output: " + JSON.stringify(results));
```